# Convert Java ENUM to XML

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I want to make a xml from enum Type with parameters.

e.g:

```
@XmlRootElement(name="category")  
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.NONE)  
public enum category{  
     FOOD(2, "egg"),  

     private final double value;  

     @XmlElement  
     private final String description;  


    private Category(double value, String name){  

       this.value = value;  
       this.description = name;  
    }  
}
```

I want to the generated XML be like this

```
 <category>  
 FOOD
 <description>Egg</description>  
 </category>
```

but, this is what I have:

```
<category>FOOD</category>
```

Any annotation from javax.xml.bind.annotation can do this?

Sorry for my bad English

Comment: Have you tried using a XmlAdapter?

Answer (score 0):

You may want this

```
marshaller.marshal(new Root(), writer);
```

output `<root><category description="egg">FOOD</category></root>`

since @XmlValue and @XmlElement would not be allow to be in a same class
i change it to attribute

```
@XmlJavaTypeAdapter(CategoryAdapter.class)
enum Category {
    FOOD(2D, "egg");

    private double value;

    @XmlAttribute
    String description;

    Category(double value, String name) {
        this.value = value;
        this.description = name;
    }
}

@XmlRootElement(name = "root")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
class Root {
    @XmlElementRef
    Category c = Category.FOOD;
}

@XmlRootElement(name = "category")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.NONE)
class PrintableCategory {

    @XmlAttribute
    //@XmlElement
    String description;

    @XmlValue
    String c;
}

class CategoryAdapter extends XmlAdapter<PrintableCategory, Category> {

    @Override
    public Category unmarshal(PrintableCategory v) throws Exception {
        return Category.valueOf(v.c);
    }

    @Override
    public PrintableCategory marshal(Category v) throws Exception {
        PrintableCategory printableCategory = new PrintableCategory();
        printableCategory.description = v.description;
        printableCategory.c = v.name();
        return printableCategory;
    }

}
```